# Content editable throws, cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent') in react app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to get text content typed from a content editable field in my react app, but getting below error;

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')
    at handleChangeCode (admin.js:53:1)
    at onInput (admin.js:157:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)



const [createCode, setCreateCode] = useState([{ value: null }]);

   function handleChangeCode(i, event) {
        const codeValues = [...createCode];
        codeValues[i].value = event.currentTarget.textContent;
        setCreateCode(codeValues);
        console.log(codeValues);
    }


        <div className='row'>
            {createCode.map((code, idx) => {
                  return (
                     <div key={`${code}-${idx}`} className="dCodeArea">
                        <button type="button" onClick={() => handleRemoveCode(idx)} 
                        className="closeElement">
                         X
                       </button>
                         <blockquote
                           type="text"
                           id="blogCode"
                           contenteditable='true'
                           className="codehighlight"
                           placeholder="Enter your code here"
                           value={code.value || ""}
                       onInput={e => handleChangeCode(idx, e.currentTarget.textContent)}
                         />
                         </div>
                     );
                 })}
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're expecting `event` as the second parameter of `handleChangeCode` but you're calling it with `event.currentTarget.textContent`.

The string passed doesn't have `.currentTarget` (=> `undefined`), and `undefined` can't be queried for properties.

In short, use:

```
<blockquote onInput={e => handleChangeCode(idx, e) />
```

Comment: Thank you very much,  Appreciate your help ! Accepted and upvoted